# Getting noclassfoundexception when integrating flume-kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

I am using Flume and trying to publish the output "/usr/bin/vmstat 1" to a kafka topic.

But I get exceptions as mentioned in the stack trace. Please help me to find solution to the problem.

==============================================================================

## Flume Config

```
tier1.sources  = source1
tier1.channels = channel1
tier1.sinks = sink1

tier1.sources.source1.type = exec
tier1.sources.source1.command = /usr/bin/vmstat 1
tier1.sources.source1.channels = channel1

tier1.channels.channel1.type = memory
tier1.channels.channel1.capacity = 10000
tier1.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 1000

tier1.sinks.sink1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
tier1.sinks.sink1.topic = sink1
tier1.sinks.sink1.brokerList = localhost:9092
tier1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
tier1.sinks.sink1.batchSize = 20
```

==============================================================================

## Exception

```
2015-09-23 10:39:36,936 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-3) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.ExecSource.start(ExecSource.java:169)] Exec source starting with command:/usr/bin/vmstat 1
2015-09-23 10:39:36,944 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:253)] Unable to start SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@12c50438 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } } - Exception follows.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/IndexedSeqOptimized
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink.start(KafkaSink.java:163)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.start(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:46)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner.start(SinkRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:214)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1300(ZipFile.java:46)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:485)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$2.fill(ZipFile.java:268)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:273)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    ... 28 more
2015-09-23 10:39:36,954 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-3) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:120)] Monitored counter group for type: SOURCE, name: source1: Successfully registered new MBean.
2015-09-23 10:39:36,977 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-3) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:96)] Component type: SOURCE, name: source1 started
2015-09-23 10:39:36,977 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-3) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.source.ExecSource.start(ExecSource.java:187)] Exec source started
2015-09-23 10:39:36,977 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:264)] Unsuccessful attempt to shutdown component: {} due to missing dependencies. Please shutdown the agentor disable this component, or the agent will bein an undefined state.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink.stop(KafkaSink.java:171)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.stop(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:53)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner.stop(SinkRunner.java:115)
    at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:259)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
2015-09-23 10:39:39,978 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-3) [INFO - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:233)] Component SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@12c50438 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } } is in error state, and Flume will notattempt to change its state
^C2015-09-23 10:39:42,250 (pool-3-thread-1) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.ExecSource$ExecRunnable.run(ExecSource.java:376)] Command [/usr/bin/vmstat 1] exited with 130
```

Comment: Give some info like how you build the project etc...

Comment: I am invoking the flume Agent using the command

bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/kafka.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n tier1 

I am using the KafkaSink from org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink (from flume's lib jar files).

Kindly advise.

Comment: Additional information,  I am using Java 1.6. Not sure if the exception

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature) 

is caused because of the java version. Please clarify.

Comment: Finally, I guess I found a solution. Just wanted to share as it might be helpful for someone else as well. 
I suspected that the scala library jar might be corrupted. So, I downloaded a new version of scala (scala-library-2.10.0.jar) and added that to the flume lib directory and it worked properly.

Comment: Output of Kafka consumer:
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic sink1 --from-beginning

procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 2  0      0 3020488  85612 729300    0    0    68    52  181  945  9  2 88  1  0
 1  0      0 3010760  85612 729244    0    0     0     0  294  879 89 11  0  0  0
 1  0      0 3008280  85620 729336    0    0   100   104  458 1224 31  5 64  0  0

Thanks a lot.